# Управление видимостью псевдоэлементов

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть div у него есть псевдоэлемент :before с display: none, как сделать через javascript что-бы после клика на этот див псевдоэлемент становился видимым?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('vis-parent');
});
```

```css
.parent #ourdiv:before {
  content: '123 ';
  display: none;
}

.vis-parent #ourdiv:before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="ourdiv">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно только добавить что в js нет интерфейса для работы с псевдоэлементами, и ответ в рамочку

Comment: @Sh4dow, я наверно старею.. =) Но неужели, хоть у кого-то, [этот код сработал](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/uGbKJ/)

Comment: Уже исправил)

Answer (score 3):

Я одно не могу понять - если вы все равно собрались использовать JS, то почему бы сразу не добавлять этот элемент его средствами? Или: "Мы не ищем легких путей"? [Примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/v4mZV/).

```js
$('#my_div').before('<p class="hidden_block">Скрытый объект</p>');
$('#my_div').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('.hidden_block').show();
});
```

```css
#my_div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #900;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden_block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_div">Кликни меня!</div>
```

Comment: :before это псевдоэлемент. вы же добавляете элемент не путайте пожалуйста.

Comment: Это я как раз не путаю. Просто пытаюсь понять смысл всех этих манипуляций. Если надо, чтоб по клику отображался какой-то контент, то зачем из него делать псевдоэлемент?

Comment: ситуации бывают разные, часто случается, что нет возможности изменить структуру, либо это затратно, и в вопросе как правило показывается кусочек кода, часто, абстрагированный и совпадающий с реальным лишь в нужных местах. и я лично не люблю ответы, типа: вы всё делаете неправильно, надо в корне менять подход, структуру, вместо того чтобы попытаться найти решение удовлетворяющее задаче.

Comment: Были бы варианты - можно было бы пробовать. А если их нет, то предлагаю то, что может вылечить проблему.

И кстати, я не предлагал "в корне менять подход, структуру" и не говорил, что "вы всё делаете неправильно". Поставьте скрытому блоку display: inline; или просто текст поместить в <span> и вы получите ровно то, что хотел ТС.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#xz').click(function() {
  $('#psevdo').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xz">
  Кликни
</div>
<div id="psevdo" style="display:none">Text</div>
```

Comment: Это не то, вы просто через HTML прописали новый элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант с помощью моего плагина.

Чистый JS:

```js
// Плагин
(function() {
  document.pseudoElements = {
    length: 0
  };

  var setPseudoElement = function(parameters) {
    if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object' || (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined)) {
      if (!parameters.element.pseudoElements) parameters.element.pseudoElements = {
        styleSheet: null,
        before: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        },
        after: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        },
        id: null
      };

      var selector = (function() {
        if (parameters.element.pseudoElements.id !== null) {
          if (Number(parameters.element.getAttribute('data-pe--id')) !== parameters.element.pseudoElements.id) parameters.element.setAttribute('data-pe--id', parameters.element.pseudoElements.id);
          return '[data-pe--id="' + parameters.element.pseudoElements.id + '"]::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        } else {
          var id = document.pseudoElements.length;
          document.pseudoElements.length++

            parameters.element.pseudoElements.id = id;
          parameters.element.setAttribute('data-pe--id', id);

          return '[data-pe--id="' + id + '"]::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        };
      })();

      if (!parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet) {
        if (document.styleSheets[0]) {
          parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
        } else {
          var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');

          document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
          parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet;
        };
      };

      if (parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
        parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      };

      if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object') {
        parameters.argument = (function() {
          var cloneObject = typeof parameters.argument.pop === 'function' ? [] : {};

          for (var property in parameters.argument) {
            cloneObject[property] = parameters.argument[property];
          };

          return cloneObject;
        })();

        if (!parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
          var newIndex = parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
        };

        var properties = '';

        for (var property in parameters.argument) {
          if (typeof parameters.argument[property] === 'function')
            parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property]();
          else
            parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property];
        };

        for (var property in parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
          properties += property + ': ' + parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
        };

        parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined) {
        if (!parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
          var newIndex = parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = {};
        };

        if (typeof parameters.property === 'function')
          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] = parameters.property();
        else
          parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] = parameters.property;

        var properties = '';

        for (var property in parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
          properties += property + ': ' + parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
        };

        parameters.element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      };
    } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property === undefined) {
      var windowStyle = window.getComputedStyle(
        parameters.element, '::' + parameters.pseudoElement
      ).getPropertyValue(parameters.argument);

      if (parameters.element.pseudoElements) {
        return parameters.element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] || windowStyle;
      } else {
        return windowStyle || null;
      };
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid values!');
      return false;
    };
  };

  Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'styleBefore', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(argument, property) {
      return setPseudoElement({
        element: this,
        pseudoElement: 'before',
        argument: argument,
        property: property
      });
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'styleAfter', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(argument, property) {
      return setPseudoElement({
        element: this,
        pseudoElement: 'after',
        argument: argument,
        property: property
      });
    }
  });
})();

// Делаем видимым
document.querySelector('.element').styleBefore('display', 'block');
```

```css
.element:before {
  content: "Мой before";
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element"></div>
```

Оно принимает значения, как в функции JQuery.css:

```
element.styleBefore(parameter, value);
```

Или же можно указать объектом. Чем хорошо указывать объектом, тем что можно менять сразу несколько значений

```
element.styleBefore({parameter_0: value, parameter_1: value});
```

Так же значение параметра можно указывать функцией:

```
element.styleBefore(parameter, function() {
  return 1 + 1;
});
```

К тому же, можно получать параметры псевдоэлементов:

```
console.log( element.styleBefore(parameter) );
```

---

JQuery вариант:

```js
// Плагин
(function() {
  $.pseudoElements = {
    length: 0
  };

  var setPseudoElement = function(parameters) {
    if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object' || (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined)) {
      for (var element of parameters.elements.get()) {
        if (!element.pseudoElements) element.pseudoElements = {
          styleSheet: null,
          before: {
            index: null,
            properties: null
          },
          after: {
            index: null,
            properties: null
          },
          id: null
        };

        var selector = (function() {
          if (element.pseudoElements.id !== null) {
            if (Number(element.getAttribute('data-pe--id')) !== element.pseudoElements.id) element.setAttribute('data-pe--id', element.pseudoElements.id);
            return '[data-pe--id="' + element.pseudoElements.id + '"]::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
          } else {
            var id = $.pseudoElements.length;
            $.pseudoElements.length++

              element.pseudoElements.id = id;
            element.setAttribute('data-pe--id', id);

            return '[data-pe--id="' + id + '"]::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
          };
        })();

        if (!element.pseudoElements.styleSheet) {
          if (document.styleSheets[0]) {
            element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
          } else {
            var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');

            document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
            element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet;
          };
        };

        if (element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
        };

        if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object') {
          parameters.argument = $.extend({}, parameters.argument);

          if (!element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
            var newIndex = element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
          };

          var properties = '';

          for (var property in parameters.argument) {
            if (typeof parameters.argument[property] === 'function')
              element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property]();
            else
              element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property];
          };

          for (var property in element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
            properties += property + ': ' + element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
          };

          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
        } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined) {
          if (!element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
            var newIndex = element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = {};
          };

          if (typeof parameters.property === 'function')
            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] = parameters.property();
          else
            element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] = parameters.property;

          var properties = '';

          for (var property in element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
            properties += property + ': ' + element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
          };

          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
        };
      };

      return $(parameters.elements);
    } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property === undefined) {
      var element = $(parameters.elements).get(0);

      var windowStyle = window.getComputedStyle(
        element, '::' + parameters.pseudoElement
      ).getPropertyValue(parameters.argument);

      if (element.pseudoElements) {
        return $(parameters.elements).get(0).pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[parameters.argument] || windowStyle;
      } else {
        return windowStyle || null;
      };
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid values!');
      return false;
    };
  };

  $.fn.cssBefore = function(argument, property) {
    return setPseudoElement({
      elements: this,
      pseudoElement: 'before',
      argument: argument,
      property: property
    });
  };
  $.fn.cssAfter = function(argument, property) {
    return setPseudoElement({
      elements: this,
      pseudoElement: 'after',
      argument: argument,
      property: property
    });
  };
})();

// Делаем видимым
$('.element').cssBefore('display', 'block');
```

```css
.element:before {
  content: "Мой before";
  display: none;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element"></div>
```

---

<sup>GitHub: https://github.com/yuri-spivak/managing-the-properties-of-pseudo-elements</sup>