# Применить .css в jQuery к псевдоелементу :before

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день.

Можно ли в jQuery применить `.css()` метод к псевдоэлементу добавленному через `:before`?

```css
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(image.png) no-repeat;
  width: 73px;
  height: 23px;
  opacity: .8; //хочу менять opacity до .2 при наведении на div
}
```

```html
<div>Блок</div>
```

Comment: [рекомендую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103237/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Игорь, а что у вас там за .vis-parent ?
Откуда этот класс взялся?

Comment: интересное решение, спасибо!

Comment: @Denis Masster, класс - родительский элемент. В JS просто нельзя получить before/after, поэтому прописываем все в CSS и щелкаем родительским классом. В вашем случае, однако, и это слабо поможет, потому рекомендую пересмотреть структуру.

Хотя в особо запущенном случае вы можете сделать такую жесть:

    /* CSS */
    div.frame1:before { opacity: 0.8; }
    div.frame2:before { opacity: 0.75; }
    ...
    div.frame12:before { opacity: 0.2; }

и анимировать классами) но это - настоящий китайский хардкор)

Comment: рядом сделал еще один див.  
хардкор мне не нужен :)  
  
спасибо

Comment: но в вашем примере я спрашивал именно что такое часточка ".vis-", откуда оно взялось? в html его нету. мы его динамически 'представляем' или как?)

Comment: @Denis Masster, откуда взялась "часточка .vis-"? Это тайны шаманства )) Просто у Sh4dow есть магический бубен )) А если серьезно, то это класс, который чередуется с классом parent посредством метода toggleClass().

Comment: Намёком на правильное решение даю ссылку на ответы в [этой теме.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103237/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: куда я попал. На див вешает ховер О_о

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно именно у псевдоэлемента изменить, то я на такой случай когда-то скрипт написал.

```js
(function(a){'use string';a.pseudoElements={length:0};var b=function(c){if('object'==typeof c.argument||c.argument!==void 0&&c.property!==void 0){for(var d of c.elements.get()){d.pseudoElements||(d.pseudoElements={styleSheet:null,before:{index:null,properties:null},after:{index:null,properties:null},id:null});var e=function(){if(null!==d.pseudoElements.id)return+d.getAttribute('data-pe--id')!==d.pseudoElements.id&&d.setAttribute('data-pe--id',d.pseudoElements.id),'[data-pe--id="'+d.pseudoElements.id+'"]::'+c.pseudoElement;var k=a.pseudoElements.length;return a.pseudoElements.length++,d.pseudoElements.id=k,d.setAttribute('data-pe--id',k),'[data-pe--id="'+k+'"]::'+c.pseudoElement}();if(!d.pseudoElements.styleSheet)if(document.styleSheets[0])d.pseudoElements.styleSheet=document.styleSheets[0];else{var f=document.createElement('style');document.head.appendChild(f),d.pseudoElements.styleSheet=f.sheet}if(d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties&&d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index&&d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index),'object'==typeof c.argument){if(c.argument=a.extend({},c.argument),!d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties&&!d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index){var g=d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length||d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length||d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index=g,d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties=c.argument}var h='';for(var i in c.argument)d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties[i]='function'==typeof c.argument[i]?c.argument[i]():c.argument[i];for(var i in d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties)h+=i+': '+d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties[i]+' !important; ';d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(e,h,d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index)}else if(void 0!==c.argument&&void 0!==c.property){if(!d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties&&!d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index){var g=d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length||d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length||d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index=g,d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties={}}d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties[c.argument]='function'==typeof c.property?c.property():c.property;var h='';for(var i in d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties)h+=i+': '+d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties[i]+' !important; ';d.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(e,h,d.pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].index)}}return a(c.elements)}if(void 0!==c.argument&&void 0===c.property){var d=a(c.elements).get(0),j=window.getComputedStyle(d,'::'+c.pseudoElement).getPropertyValue(c.argument);return d.pseudoElements?a(c.elements).get(0).pseudoElements[c.pseudoElement].properties[c.argument]||j:j||null}return console.error('Invalid values!'),!1};a.fn.cssBefore=function(c,d){return b({elements:this,pseudoElement:'before',argument:c,property:d})},a.fn.cssAfter=function(c,d){return b({elements:this,pseudoElement:'after',argument:c,property:d})}})(jQuery);

$('#target').cssBefore('opacity', '.2');
```

```css
#target:before {
  content: "Before";
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Блок</div>
```

Но я бы посоветовал изменять свойство заменой класса

```js
$('#target').addClass('new-opacity');
```

```css
#target:before {
  content: "Before";
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#target.new-opacity:before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавь просто на `div` класс и в `css` на этот класс сделай `.my_hover_class:hover:before` и добавь ты туда `opacity: 0.2` и никакие лагающие и безобразные jquery костыли не нужны

Comment: дождался ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Повесить это на ховер:

```
$('head').append('<style>div:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(image.png) no-repeat;
  width: 73px;
  height: 23px;
  opacity: .2;
}</style>');
```

ну,и очищать потом.

Comment: А если там будет transition, то этот костыль не сработает

Comment: Зачем перечислять все свойства, когда достаточно одного?