# Как получить доступ к псевдоэлементу через query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$('.call').hover(function(event) {
  if ($(window).width() < 640 && $('.navbar').css('height') === '25px') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.left_icon:before').css("width", "0");
  }
});
```

Как получить доступ к псевдоэлементу **:before** ?
Моя попытка не рабочая

Comment: а и не получите. добавьте класс к элементу, и напишите стиль для этого класса+before, по аналогии [с этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/103237/223826)

Comment: @teran, спасибо!

Comment: Через jquery нельзя получать доступ к псевдоэлементам.